# Change iFrame Google Maps Src tag using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm trying to dynamically change the src attribute of a iFrame tag provided by google maps to rotate through different maps without refreshing using AJAX.

I have the different src URL's inside a database which are returned to AJAX as a JSON response.

The response contains the URL however with added quote marks and backslashes.

I just need to remove the added characters from the JSON response and replace the Iframe src attr as the required maps URL.

[image]

```
var artgmaps = (imagesgmaps[index].replace(/\//g, ""));
$('#HTMLGmaps').attr('src', artgmaps);
```

Im not entirely sure that im removing the right characters using the 'remove' function.

Any help on this would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Just look at the result on your webpage.

Comment: @NielsNet its saying Forbidden access not allowed